# 17.10 WiFi connects to phone hotspot, but does not connect to home network

Tags: wireless, 17.10, atheros, ath9k, tp-link

I’m working on getting an Ubuntu dual boot up and running on my desktop with windows. I have two separate SSDs, with Ubuntu 17.10 on an nvme drive and Windows 10 on a sata, so all that kind of stuff is set afaik. I can boot into ubuntu, and everything seems to work—except WiFi.

When I turn on the computer, it shows that it’s trying to connect for a while (WiFi symbol with three dots) and eventually gives up, but doesn’t tell me anything. I just tried forgetting the network and reconnecting, and it says it’s connected, but doesn’t work.

If I try to turn off WiFi altogether, it seems to freeze up, and I can’t do anything in the whole settings app. I think it’s related that it takes a very long time to shut down, to that point that I’ve just been forcing it to shut down.

I’ve tried everything I could find online about this issue that I thought applied, to no avail, so I figured I would turn to your guys’s expertise. I’m not sure what kind of information you need, so let me know. It's a USB card (TP Link TL-WN722N) if that makes a difference. I found this script and ran it, hopefully it gives any necessary info: https://pastebin.com/z4xZaDKi

If you need any more info I'll get it ASAP, but it probably won't be until the post is around 16 hours old.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe the author is referring to [this standard wifi test script](https://pastebin.com/pPdu7k0A) when they say - "I found this script and ran it".

Answer (score 2):

For many years, in diagnosing and attempting to solve connectivity issues, I have preached to all:

> First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not
>   any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your
>   router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a
>   channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40
>   MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck
>   with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel
>   selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds
>   only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot
>   the router.

Your case seems like the perfect example. You can easily connect to:

```
Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'ThisNetworkWorks' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ThisNetworkWorks"
                    <snip>
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

But you cannot connect to:

```
Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Redacted1' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Redacted1"
                    <snip>
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

As far as we can tell from the available data, the only difference is that the SSID that you *can* connect to is set up with WPA2-CCMP (sometimes known as AES) and the SSID that you *cannot* connect to is set up with WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and TKIP.

Please change the encryption mode in Redacted1 and tell us if you connect.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not seem to solve the issue. Here's a new copy of the diagnostic file with that change made: https://pastebin.com/E4aZybfs

Comment: Your log shows that you connected perfectly but then, about a minute and a half later, disconnected. Did it drop by itself or did you disconnect? By chance, did it connect correctly but not pull any web pages?

Comment: Yeah it said that it connected but the internet didn't work.

Comment: Please try: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and reboot. Then: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @chili555 seems to be getting to the core of the problem. I experienced something similar after upgrading from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. My computer was able to connect to a mobile phone hotspot wifi which had the following parameters (on running [this script](https://pastebin.com/pPdu7k0A))-

```
Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'Ishank Juneja' [AC4]>
                    Channel:5
                    Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-35 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ishank Juneja"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000074e25c9ae
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4112ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

However, it was unable to connect to my TP-link home router which had the following parameters-

```
  Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Bishop' [AC1]>
                    Channel:5
                    Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Bishop"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000006a83c50cf
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4112ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

So the problem seemed to be the same and I went to [this webpage](http://tplinkwifi.net/webpages/login.html) to try and change the settings to replace `TKIP` by `AES/CCMP`. I found the setting to do this under `Advanced --> Wireless Settings --> Encryption` however after changing the setting there from 'Auto' to `AES` and rebooting the router, neither the output on running the wireless script nor the connectivity problem changed.

On scouring the internet a bit more, I came across this [forum answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2337445) and ran the commands mentioned there-

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlmvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

I am not quite sure of the implications of these commands however after running them, the connectivity problem with my TP-Link router was solved. However based on internet speed tests, I feel running these commands throttled my Laptop's internet speed by a factor of about 2-3. I suspect this may be due to some wifi driver issue.